# "Dans laquelle" ou... quelque chose d'autre ?

Tags: conjonctions, subordonnées

Je voudrais demander à ma professeure de me rappeler ou de me renseigner le mot correct pour une situation spécifique. Cependant, je ne sais pas comment formuler la question.

Après y avoir pensé, je crois qu'on pourrait dire, par exemple « Quel est le mot correct pour la situation **dans laquelle** ... on ne peut pas trouver son chemin ?»

Est-ce que c'est correct ?

Je pensais initialement qu'on pourrait dire « Quel est le mot correct pour la situation **où** ... l'on ne peut pas trouver son chemin ?»

Mais je ne suis pas sûr si c'est correct.

Quelle est la question correcte ? Est-ce 'dans laquelle', 'où', tous les deux ou aucun des deux.

N'hésitez pas de me corriger sur tout le reste de mon post.

Answer (score 1):

Tes deux formes ont l'air correctes. Cependant on entend plus souvent:

> Quel est le mot correct **dans** la situation (ou dans le cas) où l'on ne peut pas trouver son chemin ?

Sinon pour le reste de ton post, je pense qu'il y a une erreur à ce niveau:

> Mais je ne suis pas sûr **que ce soit** correct.

J'ai également vu que l'on a modifié ton post, le mot "professeure" commence à être de plus en plus courant mais historiquement on dit "une femme professeur" sans -E.

Comment: Historiquement? [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=professeure%2Cfemme+professeur&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprofesseure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfemme%20professeur%3B%2Cc0) présentant l'usage de "professeure". [Wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_premi%C3%A8res_femmes_par_m%C3%A9tier_ou_fonction_en_France) : 1884 la première professeure à la Sorbonne mais 1979 la première professeure au collège de France ou 1992 la première professeure à polytechnique. Pour dire que la "femme professeur" n'a pas un long historique.

Comment: "Dernière modification de cette page le 17 octobre 2016, à 23:15."

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/professeure

Comment: fin XXeme : "
    Néologisme créé à la fin du XXe siècle.
    Féminisation du mot professeur (autre ex. : professeuse, professesse, professoresse...). En France, l'usage tend à privilégier la forme épicène un/une professeur. L’Académie française ne reconnaît pas l’usage du mot. "

Comment: Tu n'as pas compris ma remarque, je voulais juste dire que le **métier** de prof. pour une femme est *récent*. Et que le mot *"historique"* était fort pour parler d'une situation qui date de moins de 150 ans.

Comment: AAH okok il y a confusion désolé !! Oui mais "historiquement" (avec des pincettes du coup) depuis 150 ans, on dit une professeur plus qu'une professeur**e** . Et même normalement aujourd'hui, sur la papier on est censé dire professeur.